# Creating task from commonly used composition of tasks

Tags: gradle

I often find myself running from the commandline something in the line of:
`gradle clean build installDist`

What is the correct way to make a custom task which performs this same set of tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[defaultTasks](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#defaultTasks(java.lang.String...)) can be used or the following piece of code should also do the job (mind that dependencies between *t1*, *t2* and *t3* should also be defined to keep the order):

```
task t1 
task t2
task t3

task t(dependsOn: ['t1', 't2', 't3'])
```

Comment: How would that be done in the case I described above where this is being done on existing tasks from other plugins?

Comment: In exactly the same way. The task are *present* in your build script - so can be used an referred to.